# Shopify liquid truncate

Tags: liquid, shopify

I'm working on a new Shopify template for my store. I'm trying to add up the number of chars in my title, and the number of chars in my description. Subtract this total from 200, and use the result in my truncate.

(it's because I want to get the same number of chars in each box)

I thought the below code would work.... The capture bit works (nb: if my total chars = 204, the result is 4) but it seems that truncate can't work off a variable?

```
 {% capture truncateBy %}
 {{ product.title.size | plus: product.description.size  | minus: 200 }}
 {% endcapture %}

 <p>{{ product.description | strip_html | replace: '&nbsp;', ' ' | truncate: truncateBy }}</p>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code seems to work for me. In what way does it not work? Does it show an error, the whole description, or "..."?

An alternative method you could try is to use actual variable assignment rather than capture:

`{% assign truncateBy = product.title.size | plus: product.description.size  | minus: 200 %}`

Edit: Truncate will truncate to the given number of characters, so if you only want 200 characters, then you can just use that constant directory as an argument to truncate:

`<p>{{ product.description | strip_html | replace: '&nbsp;', ' ' | truncate: 200 }}</p>`

See the documentation of the [truncate filter](http://wiki.shopify.com/Truncate) for details.

Comment: Hi Dylan, Thanks - I'm getting the same result when using your code... it's very bizarre.... as I get more than 200 chars... I've looked at the source, and there are no hard spaces etc which could be causing a miscount.... Will it see &amp; as 5 chars? That could be it...

Comment: Oh, you just want 200 characters.  Try `<p>{{ product.description | strip_html | replace: '&nbsp;', ' ' | truncate: 200 }}</p>`

Comment: Hi Dylan, yep - but I want 200 characters including the description and title... that's where I'm having trouble... I put them together, minus 200... and use the result to truncate... but it doesnt seem to be working.

Comment: What about `{{ product.title | append: ' - ' | append: product.description | strip_html | replace:'&nbsp;', ' ' | truncate: 200 }}`, or you could use capture to concatenate the title and description.  If you never want to truncate the title, then you could calculate truncateBy as `{% assign truncateBy = 200 | minus: product.title.size %}`

Comment: {% assign truncateBy = 200 | minus: product.title.size %} is a great solution - thanks :)

Comment: Is it possible to truncate different lengths depending on screen size?

Comment: Truncating based on screen size would be more appropriate to do client side in javascript, where that information is available.